# Recommendations for a hefeweizen or wheat beer?

Tags: recommendations, hefeweizen

Planning to do a Quarantine Beer Around The World company event and one of the categories is Wheat Beer - specifically looking at hefeweizens. A favorite is Live Oak given the clover and banana nodes but looking for additional recommendations.

Comment: I voted to close this question as it doesn't fit the Stack Exchange format. It would seem like the alcohol stack is dying down enough that we effectively have no moderation or quality control anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I like Paulaner's Hefeweizen (German brewer) and also Leinenkugel's Sunset Wheat and it's hard to go wrong with Blue Moon.

But beer tends to be quite regional as far as what is available outside the large brewers. Local craft beers normally don't make it too far away.

My recommendation would be to use a site like Beer Advocate or [Untappd](https://untappd.com/search?q=texas%20hefeweizen&type=beer&sort=all) to try and find local stores selling them.

Answer (score 2):

I firmly suggest [**Maisel's**](https://www.maisel.com/maisels_weisse/maisels_weisse_original_19.html) from Bayreuth (Germany) and **Weihenstephaner** from Freising (Germany), this latter both [*hefe*](https://www.weihenstephaner.de/unsere-biere/hefeweissbier/) and [*kristall*](https://www.weihenstephaner.de/unsere-biere/kristallweissbier/). Traditional - no flavours or special effects - but mandatory to try.

Also, how not to cite [**HB**](https://www.hofbraeu-muenchen.de/en/beer) from Munich (Germany).

Cheers!!